# Will Visual Studio 2010 Provide out-of-box support for the Ribbon in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I don't see it in the beta, and I don't want to jump through ridiculous hoops (http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  According to the [Project Manager](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/samanthamsft) for the ribbon project at Microsoft, in this [forum post](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=42317), the Ribbon control will be a separate deliverable from .NET 4.0.